# Print 3 boards with borders in C

Tags: c

So im trying to print 3 boards, each one is a 2d array, i managed to print the first one but im having trouble with the other 2.
any help is appreciated.

here is how it looks now:
[image]

```
void imprimir_3_tableros(char tablero1[10][10],char tablero2[10][10],char tablero3[10][10]){
int i;
int j;
printf("  A    B    C    D    E    F    G    H    I    J             A    B    C    D    E    F    G    H    I    J              A    B    C    D    E    F    G    H    I    J\n");
printf("╔════╦════╦════╦════╦════╦════╦════╦════╦════╦════╗        ╔════╦════╦════╦════╦════╦════╦════╦════╦════╦════╗         ╔════╦════╦════╦════╦════╦════╦════╦════╦════╦════╗\n");
for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    if(i != 0){
        printf("╠════╬════╬════╬════╬════╬════╬════╬════╬════╬════╣        ╠════╬════╬════╬════╬════╬════╬════╬════╬════╬════╣         ╠════╬════╬════╬════╬════╬════╬════╬════╬════╬════╣\n");
    }
    for (j = 0; j < 10; ++j) {
        printf("║ %d  ", tablero1[i][j]);

}
printf("║\n");
}
printf("╚════╩════╩════╩════╩════╩════╩════╩════╩════╩════╝        ╚════╩════╩════╩════╩════╩════╩════╩════╩════╩════╝         ╚════╩════╩════╩════╩════╩════╩════╩════╩════╩════╝\n");
```

}

Comment: "i managed to print the first one but im having trouble with the other 2" Can you be more precise?

Comment: There's a loop which prints a row of `tablero1`. Just repeat that also for `tablero2` and 3. Limiting the width of the numbers in the format specifier (e.g. with `%2d`) could be helpful too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add additional loops to print tables two and three:

```
void imprimir_3_tableros(char tablero1[10][10],char tablero2[10][10],char tablero3[10][10]){
int i;
int j;

printf("  A    B    C    D    E    F    G    H    I    J             A    B    C    D    E    F    G    H    I    J              A    B    C    D    E    F    G    H    I    J\n");

printf("╔════╦════╦════╦════╦════╦════╦════╦════╦════╦════╗        "
       "╔════╦════╦════╦════╦════╦════╦════╦════╦════╦════╗        "
       "╔════╦════╦════╦════╦════╦════╦════╦════╦════╦════╗\n");

for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    if(i != 0)
        printf("╠════╬════╬════╬════╬════╬════╬════╬════╬════╬════╣       "
               "╠════╬════╬════╬════╬════╬════╬════╬════╬════╬════╣       "
               "╠════╬════╬════╬════╬════╬════╬════╬════╬════╬════╣\n");

    for (j = 0; j < 10; ++j)
        printf("║ %d  ", tablero1[i][j]);

    printf("║        ");

    for (j = 0; j < 10; ++j)
        printf("║ %d  ", tablero2[i][j]);

    printf("║         ");

    for (j = 0; j < 10; ++j)
        printf("║ %d  ", tablero3[i][j]);

    printf("║\n");
}
printf("╚════╩════╩════╩════╩════╩════╩════╩════╩════╩════╝        "
       "╚════╩════╩════╩════╩════╩════╩════╩════╩════╩════╝        "
       "╚════╩════╩════╩════╩════╩════╩════╩════╩════╩════╝\n");
}
```

Adjust spacing as needed.

Comment: I edited your post.  It is legal to say "a" "b" instead of "ab".